# How to make the Biot-Savart law to go along a spiral shaped coil?

Tags: line-integrals, electromagnetism

How to make the Biot-Savart law to go around a spiral shaped coil?

The expression that I'm using is given here:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c4

But I want to make it such that it's calculated over a spiral, rather than a circle (as I read that what's given on the page calculates it over a circle).

Clearly I need to move into the $z$-direction, but I am unsure about how to get the $z$-coords, because the page only gives a relation between $r$, $z$ and $R$, but without $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What do you mean along a spiral? Like a solenoid? In such cases the magnetic field is just the number of turns times the field of a ring

Comment: @Triatticus Yes. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/Solenoid-1.png . Also, this question is not about such heuristics (if you say that one can get the magnetic field of a solenoid by summing rings).

Comment: Is there any region you're interested in? Like along the central axis like in the pictures? On thing is they don't need x and y be side they used cylindrical symmetry and cylindrical coordinates

Comment: @Triattics This page does a clever parametrization on it: http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/physikm/apps/biotsavart.en.php The trouble here is however how to input z and s values, because they have different ranges.